# Content page post back is firing before I redirect to another page from master page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a code that inserts a log record into SQL database, which is enclosed in an: `if (IsPostBack)` condition block in my current displayed content page. The problem is when I click on a link to any other content page from my master page, I don't know how that code get executed before the successful redirection to the other content page!

**Things to consider:**

- I have one and only general **Form** element for all the content pages
  which obviously contain the placeholder of content pages in the master page and I don't use any other forms in the content pages.
- I have several **Update Panels** in my master page that always working on
  timer tick to update user on screen notification system which also
  causes another problem when the asynchronous update of it will always post back the current content
  page with the partial post back of the master page and I don't know why because nothing inside the content template of them except the elements to be updated and not the place holder of content pages! But I temporarily
  avoided it by adding: `if (IsPostBack &&
  !ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack)` in all my content
  pages post back checks, but this is another issue.
- I have one and only **Script Manager** in the master page for all the pages.

I really tried a lot to figure out how this is possible but failed. can you please help me organize it in a better way and avoid such weird issues? **p.s**: It's an asp.net web application for employees that is very similar to Facebook.

Comment: An UpdatePanel when triggered is considered a postback and IsPostBack is set. Maybe you should check which component caused the postback and act accordingly?

Comment: I know that info, but from what I know the UpdatePanel should trigger post back of it's containing page (master page in my case) but not also the content page. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. The master page concept came later in asp.net technology and it really is just a 'skin' without much dough.